# Filtering an ActiverRecord collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Notification` model and one of it's many columns is "unread".

I need to find records in the @notification collection in which the "unread" value is false using a simple method. Such that:

```
@notifications= Notification.all
@notifications.unread --> returns a subset of @notifications which are unread
@notifications.unread.count --> returns number of unread notifications
```

How do I make this "unread" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can write either **class method** or **scope**,

```
class Notification
  def self.unread
    where(:unread => true) # depends on your data type
  end
end
```

or

```
class Notification
 scope :unread, where(:unread => true) # depends on your data type
end
```

Just call the method on the **Notification** class

```
Notification.unread # => returns unread notifications
Notification.unread.count # => returns number of unread notifications
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a `scope` by adding the following to your `Notification` Class.

```
scope :unread, where(unread: true)
```

Learn about scopes **[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)**.